# Spring @Scheduled - run concurrently

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE application in which I have a method annotated with

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *}
```

I want it to run with that cron, EVEN IF another execution is already in progress.

I tried increasing the executor thread number using the application.properties file:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10
```

But it didn't seem to work as it is still waiting for an execution to finish before starting the next one.

What is the proper way to do parallel executions using a cron in the @Scheduled annotation?

Comment: you can also allocate different thread pools for diff `@Scheduled` methods; but this will also only work if u hv `@EnableAsync`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the default pool size for the task scheduler is 1 but increasing this pool size is only making more threads available for other `@Scheduled` methods. The intended behaviour is not for methods to run in parallel as otherwise threads could become exhausted.

If you wish to change this behaviour to allow the same method to run in parallel you need to use `@EnableAsync` and `@Async` annotations. You might also want to change the pool size of the task executor. That being said, keep in mind that you may still exhaust your threads so be very careful with changing this intended behaviour.

Comment: How could I exhaust the threads using a thread pool? Would making my \@Scheduled method \@Async work? I don't what spring does when a \@Scheduled and \@Async method is called. I guess I have to make another method \@Async right? Then, how can I configure a thread pool only for \@Async methods?

Comment: If your method is taking long to execute and it's getting called multiple times, it is possible that you will claim more threads than you have available at some point. With the `@Async` method you should achieve what you're after. There is another config for the task executor `spring.task.execution.pool.max-size`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I really don't get it. If I have say, 10 threads and they are all busy, when I make the 11th call to the @Async method, wouldn't it just get put in some kind of queue and wait for one of the running threads to finish their task?

Comment: Yes that's the point. You would have used all your available threads and would be forced to wait.